# Case - Alias - MYSQL problem with a particular formula syntax

Tags: mysql, alias

I have an issue with a code in MySQL. The following query (1) throws a table (2) that show the formula of the case but my idea is to show an year or an specific month.

1)

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN monthname(Periodo) = monthname(CURRENT_DATE()) THEN Asistentes
      ELSE ""
    END
  ),
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN monthname(Periodo) = monthname(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) THEN Asistentes
      ELSE ""
    END
  ),
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN monthname(Periodo) = monthname(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)) THEN Asistentes
      ELSE ""
    END
  )
FROM indicadores_mujer
```

2. 

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMKBv.png)

Anyone know if is it possible to introduce an "as" followed by a formula like this: `CONCAT(MONTHNAME(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)),"-", year(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)))`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What error you are facing?

Comment: not just possible, it's the normal thing to do when you have an expression in the `SELECT` list. This is what aliases are for. There's nothing special about `SUM(CASE...)` that changes this.

Answer (score 0):

When i want to introduce the "as" (check when i am putting the code)

SELECT
SUM(
CASE
WHEN monthname(Periodo) = monthname(CURRENT_DATE()) THEN Asistentes
ELSE ""
END
) **as CONCAT(MONTHNAME(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)),"-", year(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)))**
SUM(
CASE
WHEN monthname(Periodo) = monthname(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) THEN Asistentes
ELSE ""
END
),
SUM(
CASE
WHEN monthname(Periodo) = monthname(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 365 DAY)) THEN Asistentes
ELSE ""
END
)
FROM indicadores_mujer

i receive the following error.

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(MONTHNAME(date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)),"-", year(date_sub(CURRE...' at line 7